# Vue.js: how to access the vm object created by vm-router?

Tags: javascript, mvvm, ecmascript-6, vue.js, vue-router

I have started a vue instance with vue-router.

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'
import App from './App'

Vue.use(VueRouter);

let router = new VueRouter();

router.start(App, 'body');
```

As we created a vm component with `new` phrase, we can get:

```
var app = new App({
    data: {
        a: 1,
        b: 2
    }
});
```

So in my *router* case, how can I access the vm object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See the documentation of `vue-router`: http://vuejs.github.io/vue-router/en/api/properties.html

We can just get the property: `router.app` to get the vm instance.

```
Vue.use(VueRouter);

let router = new VueRouter();

router.start(App, 'body');

let app = router.app
```